# Surprising simple operation results

Tags: javascript, jquery

In JavaScript, I tried executing the below statements

```
var x = 1+"2"-3; //Anser is 9.
var y = 1-"2"+4 //Anser is 3.
```

For such operations, what is converted to what?

I guess `1+"2" = 12(number)` and then `12-3`?

Comment: `-` always converts its operands to numbers; `+` (the binary operator) is addition when used on numbers or booleans (or objects whose `valueOf` returns a number or a boolean) and string concatenation otherwise. `+` and `-` have the same precedence and associate left to right.

Comment: @false `+` can also be [unary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_%28.2B%29).

Answer (score 3):

`-` converts the both operands to numbers. But if either operand to `+` is a string, the other is converted to string and it's a concatenation. Like `"Hi, " + "how are you?" = "Hi, how are you?"` So your answers are correct.

```
var x = 1+"2"-3; 
// concats the string as 12 and then subtracts...
12 - 3 = 9
var y = 1-"2"+4 
// converts to numbers and subtracts, making -1 and then adds 4 giving out 3
-1 + 4 = 3
```

This was the process.

Comment: Oh, thanks alot for that edit I appreciate your support. Sorry, I am a better Server-side developer as compare to client side, so I never knew JS has `numbers` instead of `int`. Thanks :) ^_^

Comment: Even more impressive, then, if you don't know JS all that well. :-) *(But I just have to say: But remember JavaScript isn't a **client-side** language. It's a language. It's been used on servers since at least 1995...)*

Answer (score 2):

**Scenario I**

Step 1:

```
1 + "2" => "12" //concatenation happened
```

Step 2

```
"12" - 3 => 9 //String widens to number since we are using - symbol here.
```

---

**Scenario II**

Step 1:

```
1 - "2" => -1 //String widens to number since we are using - symbol here.
```

Step 2:

```
-1 + 4 => 3 //Normal addition happens
```